# Ant is not recognized error in JMeter reports

Tags: ant, jmeter

I am struggling an issue to run ant with JMeter.

1. I downloaded apache-ant-1.10.3-bin.zip  and put it in C:\ant
2. I extract the ZIP and it created another ant folder (see pic), this is the bin folder C:\ant\ant\bin
3. I entered to control panel -> system properties -> Advanced tab -> Environment Variables
4. Under user variables under path I entered ;C:\ant\ant\bin
5. Under System variable I enter  Variable  ANT_HOME and value  C:\ant\ant\bin
6. I opened cmd and run ant -version
7. I got `'ant' ant is not recognized as as internal`

what am I missing?

[[image]][path of extracted zip]

[[image]][path of bin file]

[[image]][enter bin file]

[[image]][system variable]

[[image]][system variable2]

[[image]][error in cmd]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ANT_HOME](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/820-7054/gicjc/index.html) variable should be set to the main folder of ant and not `c:\ant\ant\bin`

> Set the variable name to ANT_HOME and the variable value to apache-install-dir\apache-ant-version and click OK.
>
> For example, the installation directory might be C:\Java\apache-ant-1.7.0.
>
> Select New again to create the ANT_OPTS environment variable.
>
> Set the variable name to ANT_OPTS and the variable value to -Xms256M -Xmx512M and click OK.
>
> Select the PATH environment variable and select Edit.
>
> Add %ANT_HOME%\bin to the end or beginning of the PATH.

In your case set it to

```
c:\ant\ant
```